# Difference between `:!{cmd}` and `:w !{cmd}` regarding alternate screen

Tags: terminal, external-command, shell, filter

On a Linux platform I see this difference of behavior between running a shell command with `:!{cmd}` (which just runs the command directly) and with `:w !{cmd}` (which passes the buffer as standard input to the command.)

Running `:!{cmd}` will switch back from the alternate screen back to the main screen, which means the Vim buffer and UI are hidden and the screen on the shell where I ran Vim are presented back, then the command output is printed and the "hit return" prompt is issued.

If I start `vim`, then run `:!echo hello`, the result I see is:

```
$ vim

hello

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

That text is also present after I exit Vim, since it's been output into the main screen, not the alternate screen that Vim is managing.

On the other hand, if I run the same command with `:w !{cmd}`, Vim simply prints the output of the command below the Ex command-line. For `:w !echo hello`, what I end up seeing is:

```
~
~
~
[No Name]                             0,0-1          All
:w !echo hello
hello

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

You'll recognize the `~`s as Vim's empty lines at the end of the buffer, and the `[No Name]` line as Vim's status line. The Ex command is also not cleared.

Why the difference?

The documentation isn't very clear about it. The closest thing mentioned in [`:help :!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3A%21) is that *"Vim redraws the screen after the command is finished, because it may have printed any text"*, but that doesn't really explain why it needs to switch back to the main screen. It also mentions using `:silent` to prevent redrawing, but that prevents any output altogether.

Documentation in [`:help :write_c`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Awrite_c) doesn't help much either, it says *"`{cmd}` is executed like with `:!{cmd}`", but it's actually referring to how `!`s are special in the command itself...

Is there a way to make `:!{cmd}` behave like `:w !{cmd}`, without switching back from the alternate screen?

Or is there another way to run an external command on the alternate screen, that doesn't involve passing it lines from the current buffer as standard input?

Comment: `is there another way to run an external command on the alternate screen, that doesn't involve passing it lines from the current buffer as standard input?` try to remove `^[[?1049h` from `&t_ti` and `^[[?1049l` from `&t_te` (https://0x0.st/iQDw.txt ).  Look at [xterm's documentation](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_), in particular the sequence `CSI ? Pm h`, and the line starting with `Ps = 1 0 4 9`.

Comment: @user938271 Yeah I guess disabling the alternate screen escape sequences is one way around it, but it's even more hacky than just passing it a line from the buffer as input...

Comment: (same behavior on macOS + Alacritty/Terminal.app)

Comment: Possibly related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24775/18609 explores differences between Vim and GVim in how they handle `:!{cmd}` output.

Comment: @user938271 I also found a plug-in using `set t_ti=` explicitly, I looked for it again and found it was [vim-flake8](https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8/blob/0c7cf6dc038223b44e3c0a702fe2acf997768e8a/autoload/flake8.vim#L143-L146). It's on a slightly different context (using `'grepprg'`) but still related. Not sure if this is a more widespread practice or not... Do you know of other examples (or have you written any plugins yourself) which use this same technique?

Comment: I know about [vim-altscreen](https://github.com/fcpg/vim-altscreen); other than that, no I don't know about anything else.  I remember tweaking the options a long time ago, but I reverted the change; I can't remember why.

Comment: I'm still interested in getting an answer here... (Itching to award that bounty!) I digged a bit into the Vim source code and I found a [`swapping_screen()`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/term.c#L3703) that tests for whether `t_ti` is set. Also [inside `do_bang()`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/ex_cmds.c#L1013) the place where `:!` vs `:range!` and `:w !` gets branched into two separate cases (checking whether `addr_count` is non-zero, which is [what `ex_write()` sends it](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/ex_cmds.c#L1856). Anyone care to write a full answer?

Comment: I don't think there's anything worth except patching source code. (BTW. Tried `if (addr_count == 0) do_in = do_out = FALSE;` and then `do_filter(...); apply_autocmds(...);` instead of that whole "if" block - everything looks fine).

Comment: @user938271 At this point I'm pretty convinced that resetting `t_ti` (and `t_te`) to empty is an answer here. I mean, the C code checks for it explicitly and there's a plug-in named "altscreen" that employs this method. If you turn that into an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @user938271 More evidence that setting `t_ti=` is the answer: docs for [`'restorescreen'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27restorescreen%27) mention it, also this [tip on xterm screens](https://vimhelp.org/tips.txt.html#xterm-screens). I really think this should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there another way to run an external command on the alternate screen, that doesn't involve passing it lines from the current buffer as standard input?

Try to remove `^[[?1049h` from `'t_ti'` and `^[[?1049l` from `'t_te'`:

```
augroup NoAltScreen
    au!
    au VimEnter * call s:altscreen(v:true)
    au VimLeave * call s:altscreen(v:false)
augroup END

fu s:altscreen(disable) abort
    if a:disable
        let [s:t_ti_save, s:t_te_save] = [&t_ti, &t_te]
        let &t_ti = substitute(&t_ti, '\e\[?1049h', '', '')
        let &t_te = substitute(&t_te, '\e\[?1049l', '', '')
    else
        if exists('s:t_te_save')
            let &t_te = s:t_te_save
            let &t_ti = s:t_ti_save
        endif
    endif
endfu
```

Look at [xterm's documentation](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_), in particular the sequence `CSI ? Pm h`, and the line starting with `Ps = 1 0 4 9`:

> CSI ? Pm h
>
> ...
>
> Ps = 1 0 4 9  ⇒  Save cursor as in DECSC, xterm.  After sav-
>   ing the cursor, switch to the Alternate Screen Buffer, clear-
>   ing it first.  This may be disabled by the titeInhibit
>   resource.  This control combines the effects of the 1 0 4 7
>   and 1 0 4 8  modes.  Use this with terminfo-based applications
>   rather than the 4 7  mode.

---

This is what the plugin [`vim-altscreen`](https://github.com/fcpg/vim-altscreen) does to prevent the output of a shell command from being displayed in the original screen buffer from which you started Vim.

---

Don't make the value empty, it may contain some sequences which you might want to keep.

As an example, I use `'t_ti'` and `'t_te'` to [set the cursor shape](https://github.com/lacygoill/vim-xterm/blob/dc6f82e33bbe466484f4f537330db8592a48aef3/plugin/xterm.vim#L189), and in the past to [restore the focus events](https://github.com/lacygoill/vim-xterm/blob/dc6f82e33bbe466484f4f537330db8592a48aef3/plugin/xterm.vim#L347) in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for making it into an answer! Yeah great point about not making the value empty, since like you mentioned, it can be used for other purposes not directly related to switching to the altscreen.