# Why does Gvim treat ansi escape codes differently than Vim in python code?

Tags: command-line, gvim, python

The following python code uses ansi escape sequences to clear the terminal screen and change the text color to red. It then prints "Hello from Vim."

```
print ('\033c\033[31m Hello from Vim.')
```

In Vim I use the command `:!python3 %` and everything works as expected. It clears the screen and prints in red. However, when I load the same code into Gvim and use the same command I get :

> ?c?[31m  Hello from Vim.

It neither clears the screen nor prints in red. If from Gvim I split to the terminal with `:term` and then enter `python3 tester.py`, then code works correctly.

So my question is : Why does the command `:!python3 %` not work the same in Gvim as it does in Vim when it comes to ansi escape codes and what can I do to correct that?

Thank you for your assistance.

**Edit:**
Additionally when I run this python script in Gvim :

```
i = input ('test: ')
```

and try to use the Backspace key to change the input, I get **^H** printed out instead of the cursor backing over the input.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/24645/difference-between-cmd-and-w-cmd-regarding-alternate-screen, the behavior I see in GVim matches the one I see in `:w !python3 %` on the terminal. Since GVim doesn't have an alternate screen, I guess that's how it can handle output from an external program...

Comment: Odd—I would have expected this to just print the text, given that gvim isn't (and doesn't emulate, AFAIK) xterm. It would be odd to me if gVim was just an xterm-emulator inside an OS window (though then again, maybe that makes sense...)

Comment: Those are **terminal** ansi escape codes, that means they work only in the terminal, not in a gui. And even that is not guaranteed to work, e.g. the default Windows console does not support those. So do not rely on those codes to be universally valid.