# :term command changes cursor type in vim

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer, vim8

I have set the cursor shape to be - `I-beam` in my terminal preference. When I execute `:term` command in vim, the cursor type is changed to block type. This change is retained even after I exit the `:term` window. The change to the cursor type can also be seen in the shell prompt even after I exit vim. :P
How do I make `:term` window to have I-beam as the cursor type?

Vim version details:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31)
Included patches: 1-2269
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
```

Comment: I'm not sure it'll help, but [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25603/how-to-use-the-same-set-of-cursor-shapes-for-bash-vi-mode-and-vim) is related if you're using bash.